# init.el and trampling of custom-set-variables

Tags: init-file, customize, defcustom, setq

My new `init.el` uses `require` to load various settings that I have organised into directories and files.  This is an attempt to tame what was a very large and messy `init.el` and `custom.el` file.  Also I ultimately hope to use `org` files to better document each setting.

I'm trying (and largely failing) to make this setup play nicely with `customize`.

My old `init.el` has grown over a few years and makes liberal use of `setq`.

But reading this:
[Advantages of setting variables with setq instead of custom.el?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/102/advantages-of-setting-variables-with-setq-instead-of-custom-el/106)

And these:
https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/b1jzno/need_help_making_my_initel_file_look_cleaner_its/

https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/9rrhy8/emacsers_with_beautiful_initel_files_what_about/

I decided to try replacing `setq` with `custom-set-variables` for custom variables.

The problem I have is that despite the fact that I've explicitly set variables using `custom-set-variables`, `customize` appears to take all my explicit settings and appends them to the end of my `init.el` or in a separate file if `custom-file` is set.  This duplicates the settings needlessly, and create more, not less mess.

What's worse is that complicated expressions seems to get rendered incorrectly when trampled, the below:

```
(let* ((default-directory temporary-file-directory)
       (emacs-temp (expand-file-name current-user "emacs-saves")))
  (custom-set-variables '(backup-directory-alist (`(("." . ,emacs-temp))))
            '(auto-save-file-name-transforms (`(("." ,emacs-temp t))))))
```

Is trampled with `custom.el` containing an out of scope `emacs-temp`.  No such issues are seen using `setq`:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(auto-save-file-name-transforms ((\` (("." (\, emacs-temp) t)))))
 '(backup-by-copying t)
 '(backup-directory-alist ((\` (("." \, emacs-temp))))))
```

It appears I can prevent customize writing anything out by using:

`(setq custom-file null-device)`

But this is problematic because `customize` settings made outside of my `init.el` and it's `require` statements, will then never be recorded.  Apart from my own (very occasional) use of `customize`, other packages may try to write to the custom file - eg `package-selected-packages`.

The way I see it - `customize` should only be writing out settings that are not already explicitly set in `init.el`, etc.  This will avoid trampling of any settings I've explicitly made.

Any other settings made within `customize` (or elsewhere) that would not trample anything explicitly set in `init.el`, could then be appended to `init.el`, or directed elsewhere by `custom-file`.

The closest behaviour to this seems to be the use of `setq` not `custom-set-variables` which seems to be ignored by `customize`.  However I take the points that use of `defcustom` keywords means that `setq` use can be problematic.

My question is - how do I correctly and safely initialize custom values in my initialization script(s), such that they are not then trampled by `customize` saving these values back down to a file, and without preventing other `customize` values from being saved to file?

Will `use-package` help me?  Can I make `setq` use safe without interleaving setup before and after initialization?

**EDIT**

Responding to some feedback, I'm going to walk through a few simple cases step by step.

As you'll see below following through a simple example as suggested by @Drew yields the correct result.  However a more complex example using `require` to pull in programmatically set customizable variables reproduces the issue.

**Attempt 1: Simplest Example - This works as expected**

1. Take a fresh install of emacs (for this I used v25.2.2)
2. Inside the empty ~/.emacs.d place an `init.el` file containing a single line `(setq backup-by-copying t)`.  `~/.emacs.d$ echo '(setq backup-by-copying t)' > init.el`.  This represents a value that I do not want to set directly in `customize` as I want to organize my own setup into more readable sections over several files/directories - I've picked `backup-by-copying` at arbitrarily.
3. I then run emacs and see the following in `customize` - `Backup By Copying`, `[ State ]: CHANGED outside Customize.`.
4. So far no surprises.  Now let's set a completely unrelated item directly in `customize`.  The logic here, is that either via automated other packages or directly by me, it's possible that something is required to be recorded directly in `customize` appended to `init.el` (by default).  So in the `customize` UI I search for and `Toggle` `Create Lockfiles`.
5. This gives me `[ State ]: EDITED, shown value does not take effect until you set or save it.`
6. To save this (and hopefully only this) setting to the end of `init.el` I'm clicking on `[ Apply and Save ]`
7. emacs confirms `Wrote /home/foo/.emacs.d/init.el`
8. The contents of my `init.el` is now:

```
(setq backup-by-copying t)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(create-lockfiles nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

OK - so far everything is as expected, now I'll repeat, overwriting the original `init.el`, replacing  `setq` with `custom-set-variables` in point 2:

1. As above
2. `~/.emacs.d$ echo "(custom-set-variables '(backup-by-copying t))" > init.el`
3. In `customize` I now see `Backup By Copying` set to `[ State ]: SAVED and set.`
4. Same as above
5. Same as above
6. Same as above
7. Same as above
8. The contents of my init.el is now

```
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(backup-by-copying t)
 '(create-lockfiles nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

Nothing wrong with this - `'(create-lockfiles nil)` has been pulled under the control of `customize`.  There is a single, correct, copy of the setting!

So now I will try to isolate the case I previous had seen.

**Attempt 2: Using `require` Example - Doesn't work as I had expected**

Repeating what was done in Attempt 1 above, but with a sightly more complex `init.el` structure.

Create a subdirectory under `.emacs.d` called `settings`, this is going to contain a single lisp file `file-settings.el` which we will `require` from `init.el`.

1. `echo "(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name \"settings\" user-emacs-directory))" > init.el` followed by `echo "(require 'file-settings)" >> init.el`
2. `echo "(setq backup-by-copying t)" > settings/file-settings.el` followed by `echo "(provide 'file-settings)" >> settings/file-settings.el`
3. Same as `setq` for Attempt 1 - `[ State ]: CHANGED outside Customize.`
4. Same as Attempt 1
5. Same as Attempt 1
6. Same as Attempt 1
7. Same as Attempt 1
8. The contents of my init.el is now:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "settings" user-emacs-directory))
(require 'file-settings)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(create-lockfiles nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

So far all good.  Now, again, let's swap-out `setq` for `custom-set-variables`

1. As above
2. `echo "(custom-set-variables '(backup-by-copying t))" > settings/file-settings.el` followed by `echo "(provide 'file-settings)" >> settings/file-settings.el`
3. Same as Attempt 1 - In `customize` I now see `Backup By Copying` set to `[ State ]: SAVED and set.`
4. Same as above
5. Same as above
6. Same as above
7. Same as above
8. The contents of my init.el is now

```
(add-to-list 'load-path (expand-file-name "settings" user-emacs-directory))
(require 'file-settings)
(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(backup-by-copying t)
 '(create-lockfiles nil))
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
```

BUT the contents of `settings/file-settings.el` is still:

```
(custom-set-variables '(backup-by-copying t))
(provide 'file-settings)
```

So the setting of `backup-by-copying` has been duplicated?

**Is it possible to use `require` (or similar) to organize my config into a modular structure of directories, without running into this issue?**

Comment: "complicated expressions seems to get rendered incorrectly ... containing an out of scope emacs-temp" -- naturally; you *quoted* the value, so of course it's like that.  I.e. you used `(custom-set-variables 'FOO)`, hence a verbatim `FOO` is set and saved.

Comment: And you apparently did what @phils mentions using Customize (e.g. `M-x customize-option`). That's the  problem: you set and saved the value using Customize. And then you also set it in your init file (with code that correctly binds `emacs-temp` etc.).

Comment: I was hoping the backtick + comma would mean that the local variable was evaluated in-place?  It seems to work until `customize` writes out the incorrect version which tramples it?  I'm retesting how it gets trampled now - I'm not (intentionally) using both methods to cause the trampling myself, but this would explain the behaviour... I'll delete `custom.el` and restart emacs.  My belief is that I can show `custom.el` being recreated and trampling my settings without me setting any of the trampled values in `customize` interface.

Comment: There was a normal quote prior to (around) the backquoted part, so your backquote and comma are just a backquote and comma -- quoted literally along with everything else.

Comment: I *suspect* you have tried to convert the code `(setq FOO BAR)` into `(custom-set-variables '(FOO BAR))`, without taking into account the fact that the latter form is quoted.  (I can't see an original working/setq version of that code, though, so I'm only guessing.)

Comment: This answer whilst not a solution has some more details and advice on how to handle the issue, and confirms the duplication of *all* custom options, when editing *any* custom option via the customize UI, as described above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10973076/2904770 - it's not really an answer, but useful reading nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have done both of the following for some options, i.e., you've done them both for at least one option:

1. Used Customize to set and save the option.
2. Tried to call customize functions to set the option in your init file.

If so, it's you who introduced the redundancy.  For a given option, choose one or the other. For example, if you want to define `backup-directory-alist` dynamically, making it dependent on your local variable `emacs-temp`, then remove its setting from your `custom-file`.

Use Customize to set only options whose values are not variable, i.e., they don't depend on anything else or any conditional handling. That's what `custom-file` is for. The settings you provide for it are not sexps that get evaluated when `custom-file` is loaded.

Put any fancy handling of other options in your init file (or a Lisp file that it loads).

And yes, your fancy handling of, say, `backup-directory-alist`, could be done using `setq`, but the effect would be the same.

(The effect won't be the same in general, because of the possibility of `:set` etc. `defcustom` parameters. But the fact of changing the value after it was first set via your `custom-file` is the same.)

The problem is not that Customize *"trample[s]"* on such a value *"by saving these values back down to a file"*. The problem is that you saved such values using Customize in the first place.

---

In your comments here you say that if you change an option, say `foo`, outside customize (doesn't matter how), and then you use the Customize UI to set and save some other option, say, `bar`, then both options `foo` and `bar` are written to your `custom-file`.

That doesn't happen if you just use Customize to set and save `bar`.  You must be telling Customize to save **all** changed, unsaved options.  Please update your recipe (in the question, not in comments) to clarify just what you are doing, and be sure to start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file), to eliminate distractions.

If you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` and you do what I described (set option `foo` without using Customize and set and save (only) option `bar` using Customize, then only `bar` should be written to your `custom-file`.

---

See also Emacs-Wiki page [Customizing and Saving](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomizingAndSaving) for more info about Customize.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.  Trying to step through this if I delete `custom.el` and restart emacs and then exit, nothing is recreated. Good. If I then load emacs again and go into `customize` for example `backup-directory-alist` (ignoring `emacs-temp` issue)  is set to `CHANGED outside customize`.  Still so far nothing written out.  If I then toggle something unrelated, say `Create Lockfiles` and apply/save then `custom.el` is created. But whilst it does contain `'(create-lockfiles nil)`. it also contains all the other customizations I've made with `custom-set-variables`. This is duplication?

Comment: Simpler example.I delete `custom.el`. If I replace `(custom-set-variables '(backup-by-copying t))` with `(setq backup-by-copying t)` in a file referenced by `require` in my `init.el`. I can see it changed in customize when I restart emacs. Again if I then toggle, say `Create Lockfiles` tho the written `custom.el` does not contain `backup-by-copying`.  In the original `custom-set-variables` version it is written out to `custom.el`.  To my mind the `setq` behaviour is avoiding duplication of a setting across 2 files?

Comment: I've isolated the issue to the use of `require` - I've written up step-by-step how to demonstrate correct and incorrect result with and without `require` and added to the original question.  Sorry it's a bit of a long read, but wanted to capture every step to be as explicit as possible!

Answer (score 1):

#### Is it possible to use require (or similar) to organize my config into a modular structure of directories, without running into this issue?

Yes. Don't add `custom-set-variables` to multiple places in your init. There should be exactly one instance of `custom-set-variables`. By default, Emacs creates this in your `init.el` file. If it's already there, you cannot use that form anywhere else without causing problems.

For your intended approach, you should be using `customize-set-variable`. Similar spelling, but important difference!