# The global value of a variable I set with setq in my config differs from the local value. How can I get my value to be what I want in every buffer?

Tags: spacemacs, variables, web-mode, setq

I want `web-mode-script-padding` to be set to 0 at all times.

In my config, I have tried both

> ```
> (with-eval-after-load 'web-mode
>  (setq web-mode-script-padding 0)
>  )
> ```

As well as simply,

> ```
> (setq web-mode-script-padding 0)
> ```

If I open a new window, and then a webmode file, the behavior of pressing TAB and other things indicates that the value is not set how I want it to be (this after reset so my new config is reloaded). So, I do `M-x describe-variable web-mode-script-padding`. I see:

```
web-mode-script-padding is a variable defined in ‘web-mode.el’.
Its value is 2
Original value was 1
Local in buffer Navbar.vue; global value is 0
```

This is not what I want. I want the value to be 0.

So I do `M-x set-variable web-mode-script-padding 0` in that buffer. Now, `describe-variable` shows

```
web-mode-script-padding is a variable defined in ‘web-mode.el’.
Its value is 0
Original value was 1
Local in buffer CardList.vue; global value is the same.
```

Furthermore, in this buffer, the script-padding behaves as I want.

However, opening a new buffer means I have to manually `set-variable` again to maintain this behavior.

**How can I either `set-variable` so it applies to the entire frame, or get my `setq` in my config to "stick?"**

Edit: In case [this was a buffer-local](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345051/setq-of-case-sensitivity-in-emacs-has-no-effect) variable, I tried setq-default, still not getting the desired behavior though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advantages of setting variables with setq instead of custom.el?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/102/advantages-of-setting-variables-with-setq-instead-of-custom-el)

Comment: testing now to see

Comment: Yea, I dunno, setting through custom doesn't work either. I've got spacemacs so I'm checking to make sure there isn't some override - custom is adding to the already existent custom-set-variables in .spacemacs at least.

Comment: this may be an issue with spacemacs loading custom set variables too early https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/issues/7970 I'll update as I explore further

Comment: If it turns out to be Spacemacs related, please add the `spacemacs` tab. Thx.

Comment: I'm seeing this in my messages, wonder if it's related? `Local variables list is not properly terminated [2 times]`

Comment: Also, weirdly, outside of web mode describe-variable correctly describes it as 0. In web mode buffers there's a line about "local to buffer," where it's incorrect. Is there a way for settings to "stick" to buffers even if I reset emacs? I checked to make sure there were no .editorconfig shenanigans. EDIT: Nope, there were editorconfig shenanigans.

Comment: There is no way to `setq` a variable such that it clobbers any buffer-local values that might exist for that same variable.  You *either* set the global value, or (when in a buffer with a local value) set the current buffer's local value.  The point of buffer-local variables is so that you *can* override the global value.

Comment: In your case, I would expect that *everything* that editorconfig sets will be buffer-local -- its purpose is make buffers under its control behave the way it wants, regardless of how any other buffers behave.  *Normally* an `.editorconfig` file would indicate established coding standards for a project, so make sure that removing the setting is actually the correct thing to do!

Comment: @phils you're not wrong with anything your saying! It's just unexpected behavior, particularly as it relates to a .vue file. In this case, I expect that vscode or something treats what it sees in that .editorconfig differently than emacs. The .editorconfig, I found out, was simply the default one provided by vue-cli when doing `vue create someapp`. However, when web-mode auto-aligns with that .editorconfig setting, it triggers the linter, that also comes default with `vue-cli`! Something, somewhere, is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The description of the variable (<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>) also mentions:

> You can customize this variable.

Click on "customize", fill in the value and click "Apply and Save".

This will add the line

```lisp
 '(web-mode-script-padding 0)
```

into the

```lisp
(custom-set-variables
```

list, or create it, if it didn't exist.

Comment: I confirm that this did add to `custom-set-variables` exactly as you described, however, the result is identical to when I tried to `setq`. That is to say, in new buffers, it says it's value is 2, while the global value is 0. This after restarting emacs.

Comment: It works for me. What version of Emacs and web-mode do you use?

Comment: GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 2, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-09-16
web-mode-version is a variable defined in ‘web-mode.el’.
Its value is "16.0.29"

Answer (score 0):

As @choroba has pointed out, this is apparently a user option (aka a customize variable).

As a general rule, do *not* use `setq` or `setq-default` to set the value of a user option.
[This answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/106/105) explains why.

(I'm guessing this question seems to be about this problem, so I'm voting to close it as essentially a duplicate of that other question. If I'm mistaken, then this answer might help.)

Comment: testing now to see

Comment: I've confirmed that `custom-file` is pointing to an existent file with a `custom-set-variables` list that contains the expected `'(web-mode-script-padding 0)`

Comment: Is your `custom-file` actually loaded - do you load it in your init file, for example? If so, does something else later change the value? You can perhaps bisect your init file to find out the latter (use `comment-region` for that).

Comment: It appears to be loaded, based on spacemacs code, but is there any way to confirm that? Also, how would bisecting my init file tell me if something is changing the value later? I searched through the file for any other mentions of web-mode-script-padding, but I'm happy to try anything! I recursively grepped my entire .emacs.d and didn't see anything anywhere setting web-mode-script padding to anything other than 0. So weird.

Comment: You can tell whether your `custom-file` gets loaded by looking at the value of its options or faces. The init-file bisecting is to help you narrow down to the part of the file that causes the problem. Presumably, it's somewhere in the part after your init file loads your `custom-file`.

Answer (score 0):

In file `.editorconfig`, someone had put this:

```
indent_size = 2
```

For some reason, this overwrote the `web-mode-script-padding` value locally to this project.

I removed that line, and it worked as expected.