# Completion to set style

Tags: completing-read, parentheses, style

I have the following function, where I would like to use completion to set the style.  But the way I have done does not reset the style using `M-x rk-bracemk-companion`.

```lisp
    (defcustom rk-bracemk-companion-style
      '("parenthesis" "expression" "mixed")
      "Set bracemk-companion-style."
      :type '(repeat string)
      :group 'convenience)
    
    (defun rk-bracemk-companion (style)
      "Indicates counterpart character when matching bracketing pairs."
    
      (interactive
       (list
        (completing-read "bracemk-companion, Sel Style: "
                 rk-bracemk-companion-style)))
    
      (show-paren-mode 1)
      (setq show-paren-delay 1.3)
    
      ;; Options: Style | `parenthesis', `expression', `mixed'
      (setq show-paren-style style)
      (setq show-paren-when-point-inside-paren t))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a couple of problems.

1. Option `show-paren-style` expects a *symbol*, not a string.
   So (a) change your `defcustom` to use symbols, and (b) use `intern` on the value returned by `completing-read` (which is a string).
2. [Don't use `setq` with user options](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/106/105), as a general rule (good habit). Why? Because some `defcustom`s use `:set` functions, and just changing the value with `setq` won't do the right thing in that case.
3. You probably want a non-nil `REQUIRE-MATCH` arg for `completing-read`.

```lisp
(defcustom rk-bracemk-companion-style
  '(parenthesis expression mixed)
  "Completion candidates for `rk-bracemk-companion'."
  :type '(repeat symbol)
  :group 'convenience)

(defun rk-bracemk-companion (style)
  "Choose a `show-paren-style' and use it."
  (interactive
   (list (completing-read "Style: " rk-bracemk-companion-style nil t)))
  (customize-set-variable 'show-paren-delay 1.3)
  (customize-set-variable 'show-paren-style (intern style))
  (customize-set-variable 'show-paren-when-point-inside-paren t)
  (show-paren-mode -1)
  (show-paren-mode 1))
```

Comment: I am getting `customize-set-variable: Wrong type argument: stringp, expression` when applying your suggestions.

Comment: Try starting Emacs with `emacs -Q`. And be sure you copied the code correctly. Works for me.

Comment: In my minor-mode definition, I use `(rk-bracemk-companion 'expression)`.  This could be the problem that is being introduced.

Comment: I get a bit confused on what to do when calling a function in my elisp code that has the interactive declaration.  Can one simple call it with parameters irrespective of how the interactive statement is set up?

Comment: Post questions as questions.