# Changing some attributes of face `mode-line`

Tags: faces, customize, mode-line, customize-face

I want to change some attributes for the `mode-line` using elisp file calls.  But I want to use exclusively the code that I write myself, without having emacs write to my init file.

Although I have been using both `set-face-attribute` and `custom-set-faces`, what would be preferred in my case ?

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
  :background "#ff4500" 
  :foreground "#ffffff")
```

or

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 `(mode-line ((t ( :background ,bglamp
                   :foreground ,fglamp)))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you want to change the appearance of face `mode-line` for your personal use, and for future Emacs sessions, then use Customize - in this case, `customize-face`.
- If you want to change its appearance only for the current Emacs session, use either one.
- If you want to change the appearance using Elisp, e.g., in a library, then use `set-face-attribute`.

---

There's nothing special about changing faces in this question, as posed. And nothing special about face `mode-line`. This is really just the question about when to use Customize versus Elisp.

---

There's also a question about whether to use Elisp in your init file or use Customize, putting the setting in your `custom-file`.  Different people prefer the one or the other.  Generally, IMO, you should leverage Customize - that's what it's for, whether you use its functions in Lisp code or you use the Customize UI.  And it's a good idea to confine Customize to a `custom-file`, not let it write to your init file.

---

This is all covered in other Q&A on this site and elsewhere...  Just search tags `[customize]` etc.

For example, [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/102/advantages-of-setting-variables-with-setq-instead-of-custom-el/106#106) covers the general Lisp-vs-Customize question for user options. The same applies to faces.

Comment: I want to use elisp.  I use the above code in elisp code already,

Comment: I do not want emacs to write to my init file at all.  I only want the elisp code I actually write to be included in the emacs setup configuration.

Comment: Put all such info in the question. Put your code in a separate file from your init file, and require it from the init file. (Customize does that automatically, and it doesn't make mistakes like we do - you just have to set variable `custom-file`...)

Comment: I shall settle with `set-face-attribute` as instructed.