# I'm unsure which option to use for setting a variable: setq, customize-set-variable, or setopt

Tags: customize, variables, setq

I'm a bit uncertain about which method to use for setting a variable: `setq`, `customize-set-variable`, or `setopt`. I did some research online, and it seems that opinions on this matter are quite varied. Here are the options I'm considering:

1. Just use `setq` without overthinking it.
2. Follow the suggestion from this website and use `customize-set-variable` when possible. https://macowners.club/posts/setq-vs-customize-set-variable/
3. Use the `use-package` macro for configuring variables in the `:custom` section. Now `use-package` is part of Emacs core and I'm already using it for about 90% of my config.

These are the settings I want to review:

```
(setq-default
 inhibit-startup-screen t             ; Disable the startup screen
 initial-scratch-message nil          ; Empty the initial *scratch* buffer
 indent-tabs-mode nil                 ; Insert space characters instead of tabs
 tab-width 2                          ; The number of spaces a tab is equal to
 fill-column 78                       ; Line length above which to break a line
 cursor-type 'bar                     ; Display the cursor as a vertical bar)
```

Let's take the first one:

```
(setq inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

When I check how it looks with `M-x customize-option` `inhibit-startup-screen` the GUI interface says: CHANGED outside Customize.

```
(setopt inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

With `setopt`, the same message: CHANGED outside Customize.

```
(customize-set-variable 'inhibit-startup-screen t)
```

On the other hand `customize-set-variable` shows: SET for current session only, which according to the website I linked earlier might be the proper way of setting this variable? It's actually interesting that `setopt` doesn't produce similar results, as it appears to have been added for user customizations according to what I read. Another possibility is that the message "SET for current session only" might not really matter?

If I go with "use-package," I think it'd be more elegant to customize all of these using the "emacs" package, right?

```
(use-package emacs
  :ensure nil <-- configure a built-in package
  :custom
  ..
  .. move the variables here
  ..
  ..)
```

When I check how it looks with `M-x customize-option` `inhibit-startup-screen` when using use-package to customize, the GUI interface says: THEMED.

Comment: On this issue, I am puzzled as well `:-(` ||| BTW, can you reduce that long section of your personal `.emacs`? Most of it is not very helpful in finding the answer to this question. One who answers your question only needs to explain the principles; then you can review your `.emacs` yourself.

Comment: Question is a dup of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/102. Beyond that (since the question cites that question), this one encourages opinion-based answers ("more elegant" etc.). Anything relevant can be answered in the question this is a dup of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Advantages of setting variables with setq instead of custom.el?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/102/advantages-of-setting-variables-with-setq-instead-of-custom-el)

Comment: @db48x Not really. I saw it before posting. Since that post was made we now also have `setopt` in Emacs.

Comment: Why not? It is the same question, with a very direct answer that has 116 up–votes. Even advanced Emacs users should use the customize ui as much as possible. Simply run `M-x customize-variable` and set the value. You are done, and customize ensures that no mistakes were made.

Comment: I don't like the way of customization UI and separate file. I will go with the `use-package` route then.

Comment: Why don’t you like it?

Comment: Although the two are strongly related, I don't feel this is a *duplicate* of the older question because it explicitly references the `setopt` macro which did not exist when that older question was asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of the new (Emacs 29+) `setopt` macro as being a version of `setq-default`<sup>1</sup> for use with user options<sup>2</sup>.

Specifically, it accepts *arguments* in the exact same manner as `setq-default` (and `setq`) -- which is *not* true of `customize-set-variable` which otherwise does the same job -- so you do not need to quote the option symbol when you use `setopt`, and you can set an arbitrary number of option/value pairs with a single call.

Like `customize-set-variable`, the code it winds up running to set the value is:

```el
(funcall (or (get variable 'custom-set) #'set-default) variable value)
```

So if the definition of the user option includes a custom setter function (declared with the `:set` keyword), that setter will be used; otherwise `set-default` is called.

(The possibility of such setter functions is the major reason why it can be risky to use `setq` or `setq-default` with user options.)

In summary, if you are using Emacs 29+ and do not wish to use the Customize UI then it makes good sense to use:

- `setopt` for user options
- `setq-default` for other variables<sup>3</sup>

I'm not familiar with `use-package` so I can't confirm how that handles these things.

---

<sup>1</sup> Just like `customize-set-variable` and the customize UI, `setopt` sets the *default* value of the user option rather than any buffer-local value which might exist.  It is therefore more like `setq-default` than `setq`.

<sup>2</sup> User options are variables which were defined with `defcustom` rather than `defvar`, and they can be set using the Customize UI.  Describing them with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> will report "You can customize this variable." with a link to do that, and you can also access that UI directly with <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-option`.

<sup>3</sup> It's fine to use `setq` in your init file for variables which are not automatically buffer-local (and do not otherwise happen to have a buffer-local value at init time), but if you prefer not to have to think about that then it's also fine to use `setq-default` regardless.

(Obviously if you *intend* to set a buffer-local value (perhaps in a particular mode hook), do not use `setq-default`.  In that instance you can use `setq-local` to be sure of setting the buffer-local value, regardless of whether `setq` would do that.)